# Cursor pointer not working on link

Tags: wordpress

please check out my website, http://pcservice.gent/

Whenever I hover over a link I see the cursos blink and then change to normal again, please does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: What browser are you using. In Firefox it works fine. Plus the Cursors CSS is also fine. I dont see any Cursor.cur files either. If you have any CSS experience then you should look into your CSS and play arround with the "Cursor" fields.